# Android ProGuard androidx keep protected method but release is public

Tags: android, android-activity, proguard, androidx

Android ProGuard with androidx lib，Activity protected method has changed to be public.

I have a basic activity extends 'androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity'.
And I have override the protected onCreate() method as protected type.
But I use the ProGuard rule like these below, protected onCreate() has change to be public onCreate().Why? Can it be fixed?

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-printmapping proguardMapping.txt
-optimizations !code/simplification/cast,!field/*,!class/merging/*
-keepattributes *Annotation*,InnerClasses
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class * extends android.view.View
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep class android.support.** {*;}
-keep class androidx.** {*;}
-keep public class * extends androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

-keep public class * extends android.view.View{
    *** get*();
    void set*(***);
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}
-keepclassmembers class * {
    void *(**On*Event);
    void *(**On*Listener);
}
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
     public void *(android.view.View);
}
-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}
-keep class **.R$* {
    *;
}
-keepclassmembers class * {
    void *(*Event);
}
-keepclasseswithmembers public class * {
    protected <methods>;
    public <methods>;
} 
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}
-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}
```

Comment: I have tried -keep class my base activity class it's not worked

Comment: do not use proguard make app bundles instead..proguard messes up code big time.

Comment: @Pemba Tamang So use other proguard? Can you tell what proguard do you use?

Comment: well, I make app bundles and let the playstore sign them. They do all the optimizing themselves. I do not use proguard or minify read more here 
https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle

Comment: Thx all the same. But this app won't be published to playstore. I search much infos but it has not be solved that I think these methods should be changed to public when I use them.

Comment: diable proguard and see
 `buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        useProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

This question seems to address the same problem as yours: [R8 changes "protected" methods of abstract class to "public"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59681793/r8-changes-protected-methods-of-abstract-class-to-public-without-allowacces/69567231#69567231)

The answers there boil down to eliminating `-allowaccessmodification` from your proguard files.

The easiest way to do that is to copy the generated default proguard file (that you don't control) into your module's `proguard.pro` file (that you do). You can then edit the latter and use it in your module's `build.gradle` without any default file.