# R8 changes "protected" methods of abstract class to "public" without -allowaccessmodification flag

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard, android-r8

I have an issue with R8. In `MyLib` I have public abstract `MyLibsClass` in which I have protected methods. `MyChildClass` extends from `MyLibsClass` in `MyApp` and after R8's magic all protected methods (including protected abstract) in `MyLibsClass` are changed into public ones, and of course in `MyChildClass` I'm getting `"attempting to assign weaker access privileges ('protected'); was 'public')` issue as trying to override protected abstract methods.

Additional info

> gradle-6.0.1

MyLib's build.gradle

```
release {
    minifyEnabled true
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'),'proguard-rules.pro'
}
```

proguard-rules.pro

```
-keep class com.example.mylib.*{
    public protected *; }

-keep class com.example.mylib.*$*{
    public protected *; }
```

Anyone had this kind of issue or know a way to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

So based on discussion [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/147447502) ,

> DON'T USE DEFAULT PROGUARD SETTINGS FOR LIBRARIES

as `allowAccessModification` is enabled in default proguard settings, which is located in Android SDK *`(\Android\Sdk\tools\proguard\proguard-android-optimize.txt)`* and my mistake was using this for my libraries.

Citation from [proguard manual](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/usage#allowaccessmodification)

> you probably shouldn't use this option when processing code that is to
>   be used as a library, since classes and class members that weren't
>   designed to be public in the API may become public.

So if anyone has the same issue I will suggest to create your own base config file for `proguard` and copy past whole default configs without `"allowAccessModification"` into it.

Also if someone interested more, you can track [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/144300603) issue. Hopefully will get separate config file for libraries in near feature.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem, and thanks to @Hayk Nahapetyan's answer, I could resolve it.

Here is my solution with a little more detail.

In the library module's build.gradle, remove the default file from the `buildTypes`'s `release` closure:

```
release {
    minifyEnabled true
    proguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
}
```

R8 no longer uses the default file that is provided in the Android SDK. It generates one at build time, and puts it in the module's build directory at `build/intermediates/default_proguard_files/global`.

Copy the contents of `proguard-android-optimize.txt-a.b.c` (where `a.b.c` is the library version, if set) from that location to the top of the module's `proguard-rules.pro`. Then remove `-allowaccessmodification`; two times, if it originally appeared in both files.

Answer (score 1):

This was also reported on the R8 bug tracker, and resolved there. See http://issuetracker.google.com/147447502.

Comment: Thank you @sgjesse, I was the reporter actually :).