# Android Library built with minifyEnabled makes all members of abstract class public

Tags: java, android, private, abstract, minify

I have an Android Library with an Abstract class containing private, protected, and public properties/methods.

When building it with minifyEnabled true, all properties and methods are made public.

Changing minifyEnabled to false, though, it preserves the original privacy status of each member.

Does anyone know why this is and how it can be avoided?

Comment: See this, even in R8 too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59681793/r8-changes-protected-methods-of-abstract-class-to-public-without-allowacces

Comment: You're a life saver @notTdar! Looks like that's definitely it - gonna test it here to verify. Do you want to post this as the answer and I'll accept it (pending the test works)?

Comment: glad to hear that. No need to accept as an answer.